# Navbar in asp.net mvc application doesn't work with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

there are few bootstraps that it works with, like the default and the lumen bootstrap in this site:
https://bootswatch.com/

but other bootstraps like materia and flatly.
I have no idea why it looks like that:

http://www.interload.co.il/upload/1975618.PNG

edit: this is the navbar code

```
   <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: make sure you have included bootstrap js file

Comment: @DeepakVerma how do i do that

Comment: can you show any working demo of your code so that i can help you better

Answer (score 1):

As I saw in [link](https://bootswatch.com/) you attached they use the latest version of bootstrap:

[image]

So you have to add bootstrap references
 to you start html file in the `<head></head>`(It looks like you need only `js` files)

**bootstrap version  4.1.3 ref** :

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried to add these lines inside the <head> element but it still doesn't work.
I'm new to bootstrap and have no idea why it looks like that

Comment: How can I send it to you? I'm also new to stack overflow

Comment: It looks like you did not put all bootstrap classes:https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_navbar.asp